# How can I tell R to round correctly?

Tags: r, numeric, digits

How can I tell R to round correctly?

Decimal Places in R
I have encountered a problem that I cannot figure out how to solve
I want R to calculate 5/26*100 = 19.230769

```
x <- 5/26*100
x
```

gives me:

```
[1] 19.23077
```

Let's try to use round(), first setting the digits to 4:

```
x <- round(5/26*100,digits=4)
x
```

gives:

```
[1] 19.2308
```

Next, let's set the digits to 5:

```
x <- round(5/26*100,digits=5)
x
```

gives:

```
[1] 19.23077
```

Now, let's set the digits to 6:

```
x <- round(5/26*100,digits=6)
x
```

gives:

```
[1] 19.23077
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Do you get the same results, or does your rstudio round correctly?

I have also tired signif()

```
x <- signif(5/26*100,digits=6)
x
```

gives us:

```
[1] 19.2308
```

increasing to 7 digits:

```
> x <- signif(5/26*100,digits=7)
> x
[1] 19.23077
```

Increasing to 8 digits:

```
> x <- signif(5/26*100,digits=8)
> x
[1] 19.23077
```

And we can use sprintf()

```
 > x <- sprintf("%0.6f", (5/26*100))
  > x
   [1] "19.230769"
```

sprintf() solves the problem with rounding, but it creates a new problem by changing the numeric value to a character.

Can anyone show me how to get r to give me 5/26*100 = 19.230769 with a numeric output?

Thank you,

Drew

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that by default, R will only print out 7 digits. See the help page `?getOption` and search for "digits".

You can change this by changing the setting to allow for more digits.

```
options(digits=13)
round(5/26*100,digits=6)
[1] 19.230769
round(5/26*100,digits=7)
[1] 19.2307692
round(5/26*100,digits=8)
[1] 19.23076923
```

Comment: Dear G5W,  thank you very much for this answer.  This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `round` function does the calculation and return significant digits based on `digits` parameter assigned to `round` function. But the `digits` setting at `global` option controls what you see in command line output.

You can modify `digits` value using `options` or you can try to convert to `as.character` to see the desired output.

My current `digits` setting in `options` is `5` still below calculation works.

```
Example:
> as.character(round(5/26*100, 6))
[1] "19.230769"
> as.character(round(5/26*100, 7))
[1] "19.2307692"
```